# Custom method "GetControlsOfType" seems to be going up Control structure as well as down

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom method GetControlsOfType that looks like this:

```
public static List<TControl> GetControlsOfType<TControl>(this Control control) where TControl : Control
    {
        return (from n in control.Controls.Cast<Control>().Descendants(c => c.Controls.Cast<Control>())
                where n is TControl
                select (TControl)n).ToList();
    }
```

It depends on this extension:

```
static public IEnumerable<T> Descendants<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                                Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> DescendBy)
    {
        foreach (T value in source)
        {
            yield return value;

            foreach (T child in DescendBy(value).Descendants<T>(DescendBy))
            {
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
```

If I have a control structure like this (RadEditor is just a Telerik control for making rich text):

```
MyWebPage.aspx  
- MyUserControl1.ascx  
  - MyRadEditor1  
- MyUserControl2.ascx  
  - MyRadEditor2
```

If MyUserControl2.ascx calls the method below, I see both MyRadEditor1 and 2.

```
public static void SetRadEditors(this UserControl control, object entity)
    {
        control.GetControlsOfType<RadEditor>().ForEach(editor =>
        {
            // Should only show MyRadEditor2, but shows MyRadEditor1 and MyRadEditor2
        });
    }
```

Can anyone help me understand why this occurs?

Comment: Do you want the last RadEditor in the list or as specific editor? Because from the code you have posted it is returning both RadEditors as you are asking to return the child controls from the two ascx control which are of type TControl. Each ascx has a RadEditor and therefore it will return both.

Comment: I am calling MyUserControl2.SetRadEditors(), not MyWebPage.SetRadEditors().  Therefore I should only be seeing MyRadEditor2.

Comment: I tested this code in several ways and seems ok..maybe I'm missing something but I don't see a way of how the recursion jumps to the parents

Comment: @AdrianIftode : Neither can I, but I can definitely duplicate it in my setup...so maybe the problem is outside these pieces of code...but I don't see how...

Comment: @AdrianIftode : I have been too busy to get back to testing this bug.  I promise to update the question when I can finally test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure right now (too tired to debug.. :-).

Anyway, try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindControlsRecursive<T>(this Control root)
    {
        foreach (Control child in root.Controls)
        {
            if (child is T)
            {
                yield return child;
            }

            if (child.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Control c in child.FindControlsRecursive<T>())
                {
                    yield return c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```